# Full text Search of browser history, through the browser

Tags: browser, search, desktop-search

Is there a browser that supports searching through the full text of the history pages' content ? Chrome and Firefox supports only searching the titles and URLs (with their omnibars).

I'm aware that Google Desktop and the likes are capable of doing that, but if the browser omnibar (or awesomebar or whateverbar) could do that - it'd be much more convenient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome does this if you go to the History view and enter a query in the search box there.

Open the History view with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
or by selecting it from the Spanner (Wrench) menu.

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: Would have been surprising if Chrome wasn't able to search like that.

Comment: But it seems to have the drawback it won't search (or cache, I guess) ssl pages, which is an increasing fraction of the web.

Comment: I was actually surprised to learn that Chrome supported this feature by default - are no 3rd-party tools needed for searching the full text of a user's web history?

Comment: @AndersonGreen - no extra tools.  Chrome will search your history like this out of the box.

Comment: Surprise! Chrome no longer does. [Intentionally](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297648). And current versions of Opera no longer do, either.

Comment: How do you do that? I just tried and searched for an uncommon word that appeared in an article I just read in Chrome (Mac OS X) and it returned nothing.

Comment: @PierreLebeaupinpi This is so sad. Any alternative methods?

Answer (score 6):

## Falcon

Since WorldBrain's Memex recently [deprecated this feature](https://worldbrain.io/announcements/search-deprecation), I went looking and discovered [Falcon](https://github.com/lengstrom/falcon). Turns out, WorldBrain was a fork of Falcon anyway, [according to the author](https://github.com/lengstrom/falcon/issues/70#issuecomment-278811825).

To use, enter <kbd>f</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd> + `your search terms` in the browser address bar.

- [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lengstrom/falcon)
- [Chrome Web Store page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/falcon/mmifbbohghecjloeklpbinkjpbplfalb)

Comment: How to get more than seven results?

Answer (score 5):

This feature can be found in [Opera](http://www.opera.com/). You can search your browser history and pull up relevant pages that contain that phrase on the page itself and not constrained to just the title of the page alone.

[image: opera search results]

Answer (score 4):

## Try WorldBrain.io

You can try out the **free** WorldBrain chrome extension. It lets you full-text search all the pages & PDFs you visited and bookmarked.

Downloadable here: www.worldbrain.io

Note: I am the founder of this project.

Comment: I like the ability to import bookmarks and previous history. Gives me a running start on full text search.

Comment: This stops working too, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

## [Try fetching.io](http://fetching.io/)

Complete, fulltext history search - indexes all pages browsed.

Index stored locally (**only available on Mac** - *Linux coming soon*) or cloud-based.

Free **while in beta** *(at least as of 12 Nov 2014).*

---

Enable this search from **omnibox** by typing `f`, `space` and then your search.

**Like:**

```
f bottlenose dolphin
```

Comment: fetching.io is great if I do say so myself!

Comment: lol feel like I'm playing pong and just had a celeb shot for the winner haha

Comment: Looks like a paid product as of May 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Since Chrome & Opera both discontinued support for full-text search, here is a current extension that I found:

[All Seeing Eye](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/all-seeing-eye/kiopjipnmfcpdambegpfmggaffjmhnkd?hl=en) Chrome extension

All Seeing Eye stores your history on your local machine, instead of in the "cloud", for greater privacy/security. And it can be used in Opera with the [Download Chrome](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/) extension for Opera which lets you use extensions from the Chrome Store.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're not on macOS, but just for reference for those that are on macOS and want to compare browsers:

Safari does this natively. Just enter a search term in the history text box:

> [image]

... and it'll search the content of the document in addition to the title and url of the site.

Comment: This is another reason I want to use Safari but it is missing so many useful extensions! Can's wait when they let devs port chrome extensions to Safari.