# Search text of webpages using browser history in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, history

I've seen this question already:
[Full text Search of browser history, through the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/42492/full-text-search-of-browser-history-through-the-browser)

I remember that Chrome used to do this if you go to the History view and enter a query in the search box there.

However, it's not working for me anymore. I can't find anything now!

Did Chrome stopped doing this? Am I missing something? Do I have to enable/disable something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, they have removed it ! I'm really angered with this decision. I have raised a bug with the chromium team and opened a thread for this on product forum. I'd really appreciate if you star the bug or participate in the google groups discussion. It really does make it a worthless browser, for me this was a the most important feature.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297648

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/chrome/200f0964-3ec5-4b26-9d15-8de6ddb14d5a%40googleproductforums.com

Comment: And guess what they did for a ridiculous reason. Check the issue comments.

Comment: I tried switching from Safari to Chrome, but this one feature was a showstopper. When you need full text search through history, you **really need it**. Thus after my few day experiment with Chrome, I'm [switching back to Safari](https://superuser.com/a/1387611/14797).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found a solution:

Visit https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity, and just search your keywords.

update:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I tried but failed to find full-text matches.

Comment: @HighGPA pretty sure, please check the updated picture

Comment: Wow I got to try this out